# VBA switch statement (or dictionary) to populate a value in an adjacent cell based off first character

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to piece together several different suggestions to achieve my desired result but I keep coming up with inconsistent results.

The workbook I am creating automatically pulls in specific values from other .xls files into column B.  In the excel example it pulls in the K221RTA11,K221RTA12, K221RTA13, etc...   Column B changes depending on the file imported for use but the common factor is that the values in range B12 through B60 will begin with "L", "B", "Y", "Z", "E", "T", or "A".  In the A12-A60 range next to the imported values, I would like for the cells to auto-populate a specific string value based solely on the beginning most letter of the adjacent value in column B.

I've tried using super long nested if statements in the formula bar and it works to an extent but is not scalable for more universal use and is incredibly unwieldy.  I'd like for VBA to listen to the B column assignment and transpose to column A.

I've updated my code to use VLOOKUP but am not seeing anything populate in the A column.  It's probably that I'm using it incorrectly.

```
Private Sub PopulateTech()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("iNTP")

.Range("B12:B60").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("L", "Z", "B", "D", "F", "E", "T", "A"))
.Range("A12:A60").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("Phone", "Computer", "Keyboard", "Light", "Speaker", "Tablet", "Router", "Switch"))


End With

End Sub

Sub TechVLookup()
Dim tech As String
Set rg = shData.Range("B12:B60")

tech = Left(Application.VLookup("L", rg, 2, False), 1)

Debug.Print tech


End Sub
```

[image]

[image: Import Splash Screen]

Comment: Honestly this would be easily doable with a lookup table, VLOOKUP, and LEFT.

Comment: Edited my code to use VLOOKUP.  Don't think I'm using it correctly.

Comment: By my comment I meant just using a formula and skipping the VBA completely.

Comment: Yep.  That was definitely the easier way to go.  End up using INDEX MATCH instead of VLOOKUP but you got me there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved the desired result using formula approach:

=INDEX(Sheet1!B2:$B$11,MATCH(LEFT(B12:$B$60,1),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,0))

Comment: You didn't lock `B2` and you don't need `B60` and `Sheet1`. By adding error handling, you could use this: `=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$11,MATCH(LEFT(B12,1),A$2:A$11,0)),"")
`

Answer (score 1):

### VBA Application.Match

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TechMatch()
    
    Const lChars  As String = "L,Z,B,D,F,E,T,A"
    Const lTechs As String _
        = "Phone,Computer,Keyboard,Light,Speaker,Tablet,Router,Switch"
    
    Dim Chars() As String: Chars = Split(lChars, ",")
    Dim Techs() As String: Techs = Split(lTechs, ",")
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = shData.Range("B12:B60").Value
    
    Dim cChar As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        cChar = Left(Data(i, 1), 1)
        cMatch = Application.Match(cChar, Chars, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
            Data(i, 1) = Techs(cMatch - 1) ' - 1 because 0 based.
        Else
            Data(i, 1) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    
    shData.Range("A12:A60").Value = Data

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try it out but I was able to achieve the same result using INDEX MATCH LEFT.  My thanks for your help.